# Show that $||A||_p \geq| \lambda|$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Show that $||A||_p \geq \lambda$, where $||A||_p$ is operator norm and $\lambda$ is one of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Solution:

$$||A|| = \max_{y \neq 0}\frac{||Ay||}{||y||}\geq^{(1)} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||} =^{(2)} \frac{||\lambda x||}{||x||} = \frac{|\lambda| ||x||}{||x||} = |\lambda|$$

I don't understand (1) and (2).

Can somebody please explain?

Comment: (1) is obvious... $f(y)\leq \sup_{x}f(x)$ for all $y$. (2), the $x$ they use is the eigenvector assiciated to the eigenvalue $\lambda $...

Comment: @Surb but how can $A = \lambda$ ?

Comment: @Surb Or  why is $Ax = \lambda x$. Is that the definition of vector $x$ ?

Comment: $Ax = \lambda x, x\neq 0$ is the definition of eigenvector. What is your definition of eigenvalue?

Comment: @Surb of course. I get it now.